# VB.NET Disable/Hide x button but WITHOUT disabling closing altogether

Tags: vb.net

I would like to remove/disable/hide the x button from my form but WITHOUT disabling closing altogether. So I want it so the program can't be closed by using the x button but ONLY by a certain key command (Through a menu item or similar). The only way I know of is to disable closing altogether which then means that the x button doesn't work but I cannot close it using the key command.

Are there any ways of disabling JUST the x button?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a WinForm application?

Comment: @StevenDoggart Yes this is a Windows Form Application.

Comment: Hard to see why a "key command" would not work, just detect it with a ProcessCmdKey() override and call Me.Close().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the properties for the form, set the `ControlBox` property to `False`.  Then, in the code, when you want to close the form, just call the form's `Close` method.

However, doing that will not stop the user from closing the window via standard OS methods (e.g. via the button on the task bar, via <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>).  In order to stop that, you would need to cancel the closing of the form in its `FormClosing` event.  For instance:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private _closeAllowed As Boolean = False

    Private Sub Form1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
        _closeAllowed = True
        Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
        If Not _closeAllowed Then
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

However, even that won't stop the application from being terminated.  For more thorough solutions, you may want to do some searches on best-practices for developing kiosk applications for Windows.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that and let you know if it works for me.

Comment: Is there a way to prevent all closing of the app except using the key command? E.g. Disable right clicking and using close window, disabling alt+f4 etc) but still let the key command close it?

Comment: @JackPollock I've updated my answer to demonstrate one way to do that